# Getting some null location information when using Google API with Addresses

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have been using Google Map API and have got the users current location and they are able to search for other locations.The information is displayed used as an Address.

When they are using the map some objects in the Address are empty such as subThoroughfare or adminArea. Other times, when the user searches for another location they are not empty and contain information.

I need an address to be displayed to the user without using the addressLine method as I need to individually store the inforamtion in my database.

**Method getDeviceCurrentLocation, gets the users current location and sets class variables in class, PlaceInformation to the data from the obatined Address**

```
   /**
     * Get the devices current location after the user has agreed to that permission
     */
    private void getDeviceCurrentLocation()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceCurrentLocation: Getting the devices current location");
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        try
        {
            if (locationPermissionGranted)
            {
                final Task location = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            // Found Location
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Found Location");
                            Location devicesCurrentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                            List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                            try
                            {
                                list = geocoder.getFromLocation(devicesCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), devicesCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
                            } catch (IOException io)
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, io.getMessage());
                            }

                            if (list.size() > 0)
                            {
                                Address address = list.get(0);

                                placeInfo.setSubThoroughfare(address.getSubThoroughfare());
                                placeInfo.setThoroughfare(address.getThoroughfare());
                                placeInfo.setLocality(address.getLocality());
                                placeInfo.setPostCode(address.getPostalCode());
                                placeInfo.setPhoneNumber(address.getPhone());
                                placeInfo.setWebsiteUrl(address.getUrl());

                                moveCamera(new LatLng(devicesCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), devicesCurrentLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM, placeInfo);
                            } else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could'nt Find Location, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        } else
                        {
                            // Can't Find
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Can't Find Location");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable To Find Your Current Location, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Screenshot, of information that is stored in the Address. Notice how the AddressLine contains the full address. But the rest of the information is different and I have no access to it**

[image: Image of stored address info]

Is there a better thing that I can use to get the current addreses information?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html seems to indicate that you have `public` access to any and all information within the `Address`. Please could you clarify what other information you need?

Comment: You can decode your Latitude and Longitude into an Address using Geocoder.